# How to call a function inside a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to call the `bar` function inside `foo` but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. What am I missing or what am I not understanding?

```js
var foo = function() {
  function bar() {
    alert('bar');
  }
};

$.fn.mainfoo = function() {
  alert('mainfoo');

  return this.each(function(key, value) {
    if ($(this).data('mainfoo')) return $(this).data('mainfoo');
    var mainfoo = new foo();
    $(this).data('mainfoo', mainfoo);
  });
};

var myfoo = $('body').mainfoo();
try {
  myfoo.data('mainfoo').bar();
} catch (e) {
  alert(e);
}
```

Comment: simple answer is, you can't call bar from outside foo, just like if there was a `var` in foo, you can't access it outside of foo

Comment: @Ivar Functions **are** objects in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `bar` so that it is a property of `foo`:

```js
var foo = function(){
  this.bar = function() {
   alert('bar');
  }
};

$.fn.mainfoo = function() {
   alert('mainfoo');

  return this.each(function(key, value){
      if ($(this).data('mainfoo')) return $(this).data('mainfoo');   
   var mainfoo = new foo();
      $(this).data('mainfoo', mainfoo);
  });    
};

var myfoo = $('body').mainfoo();
myfoo.data('mainfoo').bar();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i mean, technically, `bar` isn't a property of `foo` in your code

Comment: it's a property of the instance being created. foo.bar would be a property of foo

Comment: @KevinB When the JS runtime encounters `foo` it creates an instance. Even though the function is not used as a constructor function, there is still an instance there and `bar` is a property of it.

Comment: `var foo = function(){
  this.bar = function() {
   alert('bar');
  }
};
console.log(foo.bar); //undefined`

Comment: exact told @ScottMarcus , when do new foo, create an object and can acces to his bar property

Comment: @KevinB need to make  _foo = new foo(); _foo.bar()

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón yes, i do understand that

Comment: i prefer to use propert instead of new, but in this case is more clear and clean here is my +1 @ScottMarcus

Comment: @KevinB, when you make a new, you create a new instance of foo.

Comment: @KevinB use mdn https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new, always is better, and my english is poor :)

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón Yes, i'm not saying this answer is wrong, the wording is just misleading. The property is on instances of foo, not foo itself.

Comment: when you use new,  you can acces to all his scope, so in this case this.foo = funct... is accesible

Comment: @ScottMarcus this works for me. I'll mark this as the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you have a little oversight, inside on how to access to the bar method inside foo. So you need to return any from foo, will be an object and inside bar method. 
Here a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1jqymffg/18/) , with a very little touched from yours:

```
var foo = function(){
    return {
    bar: function() {
    alert('bar');
    }
  }
};

$.fn.mainfoo = function() {
      console.log('mainfoo');

        return this.each(function(key, value){

      if ($(this).data('mainfoo')) return $(this).data('mainfoo');

            var mainfoo = new foo();

      $(this).data('mainfoo', mainfoo);

        });    
};

var myfoo = $('body').mainfoo();
try{
    myfoo.data('mainfoo').bar();
}catch(e){
    console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: Your English is a bit rough. I'm not sure what that first sentence means.

Comment: ;( yes i lear it by myself, sorry. I edited expect it was more clearer

Comment: No shame in that. I'm just suggesting you get a little help clearing it up.

Comment: @isherwood no matter, the idea is the code works and its enought clearer

Answer (score 0):

two ways

```
var foo = function(){
    return {
        bar: function(){ alert('bar')}
    };
};
jQuery.fn.mainfoo = function() {
    ///
    var mainfoo = foo();
    ///
};
```

other way

```
var foo = function(){
    this.bar = function() {
        alert('bar');
    }
};
$.fn.mainfoo = function() {
    var mainfoo = new foo();  
};
```